# Flutter: add Divider to Wrap

Tags: flutter

I would like to add `Divider` to a wrap depending if a child is in a new line (i.e. new run) or not.

In the large screen (on the left) the Availability widget fits in the wrap horizontally, so I want to add a `VerticalDivider`. While on the right it doesn't fit, so it goes vertically and I want to add a `Divider`.

I don't know which condition to write since I don't know how to check if `Availability` widget is a new line or not.

[image]

Comment: why don't you try with responsive condition? You can try with `LayoutBuilder` . Using `Wrap` is not a good approach. Here some explanation and Demo  https://medium.com/easyread/3-options-for-creating-responsive-layouts-in-flutter-app-live-demo-68b0c0e955ab